# Create two columns from one, based on a different where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table has two rows for an employee with different status and employee code values and I want to write a query to generate 1 row with two columns for employee codes based on different status.

Here is data from the table,

```
EmployeeId  First_Name  Last_Name  Sex  Employee_Code  Status
----------  ----------  ---------  ---  -------------  ------
  91224       Jane        Scott     F      7754        Active
  91224       Jane        Scott     F      8234       Inactive
```

This is my query,

```
SELECT ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, '') AS EmployeeId, 
e.First_Name AS FirstName, e.Last_Name AS LastName,
e.Sex AS Gender, 
e1.Employee_Code AS CurrentEmployeeCode, 
e2.Employee_Code AS PreviousEmployeeCode
FROM #tempEmployee e
LEFT JOIN #tempEmployee e1 ON e.EmployeeId = e1.EmployeeId AND e.Status = 'Inactive'
LEFT JOIN #tempEmployee e2 ON e.EmployeeId = e2.EmployeeId AND e.Status = 'Active'
WHERE e.EmployeeId = '91224'
```

This is my result:

```
EmployeeId  FirstName  LastName  Gender  CurrentEmployeeCode  PreviousEmployeeCode
----------  ---------  --------  ------  -------------------  --------------------
91224         Jane      Scott      F       NULL                      8234
91224         Jane      Scott      F       7754                      NULL
```

I want to have one row for this employeeId with two columns currentemployeecode and previousemployeecode.

Comment: You may consider posting some sample data from the actual table `#tempEmployee` alonng with your result table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with some aggregation and a group by

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, '') AS EmployeeId, 
    e.First_Name AS FirstName, 
    e.Last_Name AS LastName,
    e.Sex AS Gender, 
    MAX(e1.Employee_Code) AS CurrentEmployeeCode, 
    MAX(e2.Employee_Code) AS PreviousEmployeeCode
FROM #tempEmployee e
LEFT JOIN #tempEmployee e1 
    ON e.EmployeeId = e1.EmployeeId 
    AND e.Status = 'Inactive'
LEFT JOIN #tempEmployee e2 
    ON e.EmployeeId = e2.EmployeeId 
    AND e.Status = 'Active'
WHERE e.EmployeeId = '91224'
GROUP BY 
    ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, ''),
    e.First_Name, 
    e.Last_Name,
    e.Sex
```

I'm not even sure you need to link back to the original table, give this a go;

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, '') AS EmployeeId, 
    e.First_Name AS FirstName, 
    e.Last_Name AS LastName,
    e.Sex AS Gender, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN e.Status = 'Inactive' THEN e.Employee_Code ELSE 0 END) AS CurrentEmployeeCode, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN e.Status = 'Active' THEN e.Employee_Code ELSE 0 END) AS PreviousEmployeeCode
FROM #tempEmployee e
WHERE e.EmployeeId = '91224'
GROUP BY 
    ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, ''),
    e.First_Name, 
    e.Last_Name,
    e.Sex
```

Full code with test data;

```
CREATE TABLE #tempEmployee (EmployeeId int, First_Name varchar(4), Last_Name varchar(5), Sex varchar(1), Employee_Code int, Status varchar(8))
INSERT INTO #tempEmployee (EmployeeId, First_Name, Last_Name, Sex, Employee_Code, Status)
VALUES
(91224,'Jane','Scott','F',7754,'Active')
,(91224,'Jane','Scott','F',8234,'Inactive')

SELECT 
    ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, '') AS EmployeeId, 
    e.First_Name AS FirstName, 
    e.Last_Name AS LastName,
    e.Sex AS Gender, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN e.Status = 'Inactive' THEN e.Employee_Code ELSE 0 END) AS CurrentEmployeeCode, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN e.Status = 'Active' THEN e.Employee_Code ELSE 0 END) AS PreviousEmployeeCode
FROM #tempEmployee e
WHERE e.EmployeeId = '91224'
GROUP BY 
    ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, ''),
    e.First_Name, 
    e.Last_Name,
    e.Sex
```

Result

```
EmployeeId  FirstName   LastName    Gender  CurrentEmployeeCode PreviousEmployeeCode
91224       Jane        Scott       F       8234                7754
```

Comment: This still gives me two rows. One where CurrentEmployeeCode is null and one where PreviousEmployeeCode is null.

Comment: I've just tweaked the code slightly. I've also tested this with the final query as shown, it's definitely only giving me the one row with the data you have supplied.

Comment: check my answer - status was looking to the wrong table

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the context. Since you have only **two values**, the easy way to do this is just to:

```
SELECT ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, '') AS EmployeeId, 
e.First_Name AS FirstName, e.Last_Name AS LastName,
e.Sex AS Gender, 
Min(e1.Employee_Code) AS PreviousEmployeeCode
Max(e1.Employee_Code) AS CurrentEmployeeCode
FROM #tempEmployee e
LEFT JOIN #tempEmployee e1 ON e.EmployeeId = e1.EmployeeId 
WHERE e.EmployeeId = '91224'
```

I am also asuming that the new employee code would be higher.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with a CTE and COALESCE.

```
;WITH InactiveEmp
AS (
    SELECT EmployeeId
        ,First_Name
        ,Last_Name
        ,Sex
        ,Employee_Code
    FROM #tempEmployee
    WHERE STATUS = 'Inactive'
    )
    ,ActiveEmp
AS (
    SELECT EmployeeId
        ,First_Name
        ,Last_Name
        ,Sex
        ,Employee_Code
    FROM #tempEmployee
    WHERE STATUS = 'Active'
    )
SELECT COALESCE(ia.EmployeeId, a.EmployeeId) AS EmployeeId
    ,COALESCE(ia.First_Name, a.First_Name) AS FirstName
    ,COALESCE(ia.Last_Name, a.Last_Name) AS LastName
    ,COALESCE(ia.Sex, a.Sex) AS Gender
    ,ia.Employee_Code AS CurrentEmployeeCode
    ,a.Employee_CodE AS PreviousEmployeeCode
FROM InactiveEmp ia
FULL JOIN ActiveEmp a
    ON ia.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeID
```

Comment: this fails if the emp does not have either status

Comment: Fair enough.  I made the assumption it was one or the other.  You are correct, though, if there are 3 or more statuses this would not be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

you were just checking status on the wrong (left) table
**e**.Status = 'Inactive'

```
SELECT distinct 
ISNULL(e.EmployeeId, '') AS EmployeeId, 
e.First_Name AS FirstName, e.Last_Name AS LastName,
e.Sex AS Gender
, e1.Employee_Code AS CurrentEmployeeCode , e1.Status 
, e2.Employee_Code AS PreviousEmployeeCode, e2.Status
FROM #tempEmployee e
LEFT JOIN #tempEmployee e1 ON e.EmployeeId = e1.EmployeeId AND e1.Status = 'Inactive'
LEFT JOIN #tempEmployee e2 ON e.EmployeeId = e2.EmployeeId AND e2.Status = 'Active'
WHERE e.EmployeeId = '91224'
```